# Errors on Adding ListView to Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to add a listview to an existing android fragment. I made a layout xml file for items in the listview, modified the previous fragment.xml, wrote a new arrayadapter and added something to the fragment.java. But whenever I call the notifyDataSetChanged() method in the fragment.java, I got an error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0, and then the app crashes. Below please find my codes.

```
layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_checkIcon"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:contentDescription="Provider icon"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_checkIcon"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_checkName"
            android:text="Provider name"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_checkInDate"
            android:text="Check In Date"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#888888"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_checkPoints"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="100分"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#CF1A12"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.MeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/me_bg2"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fake_head"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_fake_head"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_fake_head"
            android:text="--"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_name"
            android:text="积分"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/me_points_bg"
            android:id="@+id/tv_points"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_histories"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Arrayadapter.java

```
public class RecordArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CheckInRecord.CheckInRec> {
    private int resourceId;
    private Context context;
    private List<CheckInRecord.CheckInRec> checkInRecList;

    public RecordArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<CheckInRecord.CheckInRec> checkInRecList)
    {
        super(context, resourceId, checkInRecList);
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.checkInRecList = checkInRecList;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_checkName);
        TextView textViewCheckInDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_checkInDate);
        TextView textViewPoints = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_checkPoints);
        ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_checkIcon);

        CheckInRecord.CheckInRec checkInRec = checkInRecList.get(position);
        textViewName.setText(checkInRec.providerName);
        textViewCheckInDate.setText(checkInRec.checkInDate);
        textViewPoints.setText(checkInRec.providerPoints);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(checkInRec.providerIcon, imageViewIcon, Utility.displayImageOptions);

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getIsPrize(int position) {return (this.checkInRecList.get(position).isPrize);}

}
```

fragment.java

```
public class MeFragment extends Fragment implements ApiRequestDelegate {


    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewPoints;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private RecordArrayAdapter recordArrayAdapter;
    private List<CheckInRecord.CheckInRec> checkInRecList = new ArrayList<CheckInRecord.CheckInRec>();


    public MeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ApiManager.getInstance().checkInHistories(AppDataManager.getInstance().getUserToken(), AppDataManager.getInstance().getUserPhone(),
                Utility.getPictureSize(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_me, container, false);

        textViewName = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        textViewPoints = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_points);

        ListView listViewRec = (ListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lv_histories);

        recordArrayAdapter = new RecordArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.row_record, checkInRecList);
        listViewRec.setAdapter(recordArrayAdapter);

        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void apiCompleted(ApiResult apiResult, HttpRequest httpRequest) {
        if (progressDialog!=null){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (!apiResult.success){
            ApiManager.handleMessageForReason(apiResult.failReason, getActivity());
            return;
        }

        CheckInRecord checkInRecord = (CheckInRecord) apiResult.valueObject;
        if (checkInRecord != null){
            textViewName.setText(checkInRecord.userName);
            textViewPoints.setText(String.format("积分%d分", checkInRecord.userPoints));
            this.checkInRecList.clear();
            this.checkInRecList.addAll(checkInRecord.checkInRecList);

            recordArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the complete error log

Comment: Glad that you have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `checkInRec.providerName`, `checkInRec.checkInDate` and `checkInRec.providerPoints` values that you set as TextView text have a type of `String` and cast it to `String` if it's integer.

```
// cast to String if checkInRec.checkInDate is integer
textViewPoints.setText(String.valueOf(checkInRec.providerPoints));
```

**UPD:**

It seems ListView is located behind header view. Try to change root view of `fragment.xml` from `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` attribute. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:context=".fragment.MeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/me_bg2"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fake_head"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_fake_head"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_fake_head"
            android:text="--"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_name"
            android:text="积分"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/me_points_bg"
            android:id="@+id/tv_points"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_histories"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But the list is blank, do you have any ideas?

Comment: hi, i cannot find the difference between your code and mine. Actually, the number of items is the same as the number of records in the server, but just every item with blank textviews and gray images

Comment: Oops... It is formatting issue, SO parser ate root tag. I just fixed it. See the code.

Comment: Are you sure that the data you got from server and parse is valid? Debug your code and see what the values you are setting to TextViews in `getView` method.

Comment: Hi, I guess there might me sth wrong in the adapter, so how to determine whether the objects in getView are valid or not. It is fine if you do not have time for my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59919/discussion-between-gilbertlee-and-erakitin).